# jQuery replaceWith when url changes

Tags: jquery

I have an `<a>` for "Log in" as `<a href="#" id="login">Log in</a>`.

I'd like to replace the body of the `<a>` only when the url is on a certain page. How might you go about doing that with jQuery?

**Clarification:** When I'm at my `/login` URL, I want to change the `<a>` from:

`<a href="/login">Log in</a>`

to

`<a href="/signup">Sign up</a>`

I have the following jQuery but don't know how to apply it to the specific link when the user is on a certain page.

```
$('a#login').html('<a href="/">Sign up</a>');
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you have any control at all over the _server-side_ code, you should be making this change there. Then you won't need to fix it after the fact in the client browser.

Comment: Great point. I'll handle it on the server-side then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var certainURL = "the url you want";
    if (window.location === certainURL) {
        $("a#login").attr('href', certainURL);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

site url : /login

```
<a href="#" id="login">Log in</a>
```

if you wanna replace it, do like this

```
$(function(){
    var url = document.location.href;
    var site = url.split('/');

    if( site[site.length-1] === 'login')
        $('a#login').replaceWith('<a href="/signup">Sign up</a>');
});
```

but if you just want to replace the 'text' and 'href', do like this

```
$(function(){
    var url = document.location.href;
    var site = url.split('/');

    if( site[site.length-1] === 'login')
        $('a#login').text('Sign up').attr('href','/signup');
});
```

hopefully help  :D

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this,

```
<a id="login" href="#">Log in</a>.
```

Jquery,

```
 var currentUrl=window.location;
    if(currentUrl=="url"){
       $('a#login').attr('href','new url')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question a bit if you don't mind taking another look.